# awk function to keep last occurrence of records containing two same fields

Tags: function, awk

I am trying to make an  inventory of different kinds of vehicles. At this step my data look like

```
land; road; car (blue); 1956
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979
air; -; plane (black); 1984
air; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (red); 1998
```

I first need to keep the last occurrence of lines with the same first and second fields,

```
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979
air; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (red); 1998
```

and then sort the third, fifth fields if they exist with their associated adjacent fields (fourth, sixth, or eighth respectively) by descending order
In order to get:

```
land; road; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979; car (blue); 1956
air; -; helicopter (red); 1998; plane (black); 1984
```

Answer (score 1):

One way. You will need `GNU awk` because I use the `delete` instruction to empty arrays. In case of error it will be needed to use a `for` loop to delete each key individually.

Assuming `infile` with data:

```
land; road; car (blue); 1956
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979
air; -; plane (black); 1984
air; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (red); 1998
```

And the `awk` program in `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
        ## Split line in ";" with spaces between it.
        FS = "[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*";

        ## In output separate fields with a ";" followed by a space.
        OFS = "; ";
}

## First line is special, save the line with its first two fields as a key of
## a hash to check repeated ones.
FNR == 1 {
        keys[ $1 OFS $2 ] = $0;
        next;
}

## For every line...
{
        ## Extract the key (first two fields).
        key = $1 OFS $2;

        ## I want to get last line of each key. If it exists in the hash may be the last one, but
        ## can't be sure until I read the next one, so save its content, read next line and wait...
        if ( key in keys ) {
                keys[ key ] = $0;
                next;
        }

    ## Order and print vehicles by date :-)
        order_and_print_vehicles_by_date(keys);

        ## Empty the hash.
        delete keys;

        ## Save new kind of vehicles.
        keys[ key ] = $0;
}

END {
        order_and_print_vehicles_by_date(keys);
}


function order_and_print_vehicles_by_date(keys,                 ordered_line, dates, vehicles) {

        ## "keys" has only one key, get it.
        for ( k in keys ) {
                line = keys[ k ];
        }

        ## Remove the key (first two fields) of the line.
        sub( /^([^;]*;){2}[[:space:]]*/, "", line );

        ## Get vehicles and dates from the line.
        split( line, data, /;[[:space:]]*/ );

        ## Even positions of the array are vehicles, odd positions are for dates. Extract them.
        for ( i = length( data ); i >= 1; i-- ) {
                if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
                        dates[ ++d ] = data[ i ];
                }
                else {
                        vehicles[ dates[d] ] = data[ i ];
                }
        }

        ## Sort dates in descendant order.
        asort( dates, ordered_dates, "@val_num_desc" );

        ## Get the line to print.
        printf "%s%s", k, OFS;
        for ( i = 1; i <= length( ordered_dates ); i++ ) {
                ordered_line = ordered_line sprintf( "%s%s%s%s", vehicles[ ordered_dates[i] ], OFS, ordered_dates[i], OFS );
        }

        ## Remove last ";" from the line and print.
        sub( /[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*$/, "", ordered_line );
        printf "%s\n", ordered_line;
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

That yields:

```
land; road; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979; car (blue); 1956
air; -; helicopter (red); 1998; plane (black); 1984
```

Comment: @lqdo: Ok. I read that you wanted a function but I don't know all the context of your program. Even so, I included most of the code inside a function. The `END` section it's run after reading all input of the file, so it's a special case to process last record.

Answer (score 0):

I gues this is what you are looking for:

```
awk -F";" '{a[$1$2]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' your_file | sort -k 2.2r -t"("
```

testetd below:

```
> cat temp
land; road; car (blue); 1956
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979
air; -; plane (black); 1984
air; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (red); 1998
air2; -; plane (black); 1984
air2; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (green); 1998
land2; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995
land2; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (zcar); 1995; car (red); 1979
> nawk -F";" '{a[$1$2]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' temp | sort -k 2.2r -t"("
land2; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (zcar); 1995; car (red); 1979
land; road; car (blue); 1956 ; car (yellow); 1995; car (red); 1979
air; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (red); 1998
air2; -; plane (black); 1984; helicopter (green); 1998
```